# Python, can someone explain this script to me?

Tags: python, ajax, json

I **know nothing about Python** but would like to clone this script with jquery using ajax post. 
To do that i need to know what this script is doing in the first place.

```
import requests
import json

params = {'nearest': True, 'imageurl': img, 'timestamp':140000}

request = requests.post('http://example.com/api/upload/', data=params)
output = request.json()
print json.dumps(output['files'][0]['predicted_classes'])
```

Thanks. If something is unclear please comment and i'll clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
```

above line imports two modules Request(contain methods for sending request to the server) and json(to serialise/deserialise  data to json)

```
params = {'nearest': True, 'imageurl': img, 'timestamp':140000}
```

creating a dictionary with key value .here it is used to pass parameter

```
response= requests.post('http://example.com/api/upload/', data=params)
```

this is used to send Post resquest . here post is method in request module with `parameters(Url,data_to_send)`

```
output = response.json()
```

output has the response in json format

```
print json.dumps(output['files'][0]['predicted_classes'])
```

json dumps is used to convert to json format

Answer (score 0):

This code does the following:

1) #First it imports the external modules.
2) #Next it defines params as a dictionary with 3 entries.
3) #Then it uses request libraries to get the file and transfigures "params" into a json object 
4) #Lastly, the code prints the request.

To see the request you may need to use an image library to see what you gathered from the World Wide Web.